# If the potential difference across the ends of a conductor is 2 Volts then does that mean that the current flowing through the conductor is 2 Ampere

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

According to Ohm's law, the current flowing through a conductor is directly proprtional to the potential difference applied across its ends. So if the pd is 2 V then the charge flowing through the conductor at any Cross section of it should be equal to 2 Couloumb per second or 2 Ampere.

Comment: What you've described is if they are equal, however as you state they are directly proportional, and this is different from being equal.  Do you know what the constant of proportionality is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the linear equation: y = 3 x. The slope of this line is 3.
Mathematically, we can say that y ~ x. [y is proportional to x]. If we wish to express the proportionality as an equation, we need to insert a "constant of proportionality".
In this specific case, the constant of proportionality is the slope, (3).
Now we can write the equation as: y = 3 x.

In the case of Ohm's Law, (I) ~ V [NOTE: this was the original format, as Ohm did it. We have switched it around to V ~ (I) because it's easier to manipulate (V) in the lab.]
Applying the requirement mentioned above, to make an equation out of V ~ (I); we need a constant of proportionality. It so happens that the constant in this case is (R); the resistance of the material being used.
Ohm's Law then is rewritten as: V = R (I). 
Notice that this differs from the normal way we write Ohm's Law [V = (I) R]. What caused this alteration? Historically, Ohm showed that [delta V / delta (I) = slope = R].

Comment: Thanks this helped.... A lot. I'm a 10th grade kid... I dont know who are but still thanks a lot 

Answer (score 1):

When two quantities are directly proportional, a "constant of proportionality" is required to form an equality.
It is true that according to Ohm's Law, the current thru a conductor is directly proportional to the PD across. The constant of proportionality in this case would be (R), the resistance of the conductor in ohms (symbol: Greek letter Omega).
Only when R = 1 ohm would the current thru the conductor be 2 A. For all other values of R, the current would be (V / R).

Comment: Thanks but can you please like explain briefly what a constant of proportionality is and why why it is dropping over here in Ohm's equation out of nowhere. 